# How to add permissions in andoridmanifest.xml through a Java Class ?

Tags: java, android, location, android-manifest

I want to know the location of my android device in terms of longitude and latitude through a java class in the other package in the same project but not through an android activity in the default package. For this I need to set the permission in the androidmanifest.xml file through a Java Class. How do I do that please help me with it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For this I need to set the permission in the androidmanifest.xml file through a Java Class

That is not possible, nor is is necessary. Permissions are for the whole app, not for individual classes. Just put the `<uses-permission>` element in the manifest.

Comment: Well, I am developing a security product, and not doing application development. So I need help in concern to adding permission to android manifest through java.I am not permitted to change the source code of the application.